# IF Isset not working on lopping with [$key]

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

i have 2 arrays
$data1 and $data2

when request $data2 **is_null** or **empty**, 
always show error

```
Undefined offset: 0
```

on line

```
{{$data2[$key]->month}}
```

**My blade**

```
@foreach($data1 as $key => $value)
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->id}}</td>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->Parameters->name}}</td>
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->month}}</td>

 @if(isset($data2))
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data2[$key]->month}}</td>
 @endif
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking isset for `$data3` but you instead need to check for `$data2[$key]`

```
@foreach($data1 as $key => $d1)
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->id}}</td>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->Parameters->name}}</td>
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->month}}</td>

 @if(isset($data2[$key]))
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data2[$key]->month}}</td>
 @endif
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

Also you can change `$data1[$key]` to `$d1`

```
@foreach($data1 as $key => $d1)
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$d1->id}}</td>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$d1->Parameters->name}}</td>
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$d1->month}}</td>

 @if(isset($data2[$key]))
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data2[$key]->month}}</td>
 @endif
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry typo, i mean @if(isset($data2))

Comment: `@if(isset($data2))` still won't check if the index exists. You need to use `@if(isset($data2[$key]))`

Comment: @RAVIBANGKITNURZIKRILLAH :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check whether `$data2[$key]` is set `@if(isset($data2[$key]))`:

```
@foreach($data1 as $key => $d1)
<tr>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->id}}</td>
  <td align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->Parameters->name}}</td>
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data1[$key]->month}}</td>

 @if(isset($data2[$key]))
  <td align="center" align="center" style="padding: 10px">{{$data2[$key]->month}}</td>
 @endif
</tr> 
@endforeach
```